Almost sure convergence of double averages of IID random variables
Let $ \{X_i\}_{i=1}^{P} $ and $ \{Y_j\}_{j=1}^{Q} $ be two sequences of independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables. $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent between all pairs of $i$ and $j$.  Say $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere as maps $x$ and $y$ to a real value. Assume that $ E[f(X_i, Y_j)] = \mu $ and $ E[f(X_i, Y_j)^2] $ exist and are finite.
Due to the strong law of large numbers, we can show that
$$\frac{1}{P} \sum_{i=1}^{P} \frac{1}{Q} \sum_{j=1}^{Q} f(X_i, Y_j) \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \mu$$
as both $P$ and $Q$ go to infinity. However, I am unsure how fast $P$ and $Q$ should grow relative to each other. My intuition is that $P$ and $Q$ need to grow at the same rate, i.e. $\mathcal{O}(P/Q)=1$, but how do I show this rigorously? or how do I show that they do not need to grow at the same rate?

To understand correctly: You don't assume that $(X_i){i \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_j){j \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent. As sequences they may be identical even?

I should have clarified. ${X_i}$ and ${Y_i}$ are independent. Edited the main post to reflect this.

Do you mean that the sequences $(X_i){i\geq 1}$ and $(Y_j){j\geq 1}$ are independent or that for each fixed $i$ and $j$, $X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$?

The latter. For each fixed $i$ and $j$, $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independently sampled. Also, for each fixed $i$ and $j$, $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independently sampled.

I see, so in particular we do not have the independence between, says, $X_i$ and the vector $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$. In this case I would like to see how you prove what follows after "we can show that" in the opening post.

@DavideGiraudo I am simply saying: we construct a vector X with P elements who are independently sampled from a distribution A. Also to construct vector Y, we independently sample its elements independently from a distribution B. Therefore everything is independent from each other. We do have independence between $X_i$ and $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$. I am trying to understand what makes my set up statement so misleading.

Okay so now I understand, so the vectors $(X_1,\dots,X_p)$ and $(Y_1,\dots,Y_q)$ are independent. I think that I can come up with something.

Let us give a name to the partial sums
$$
S_{P,Q}(f)=\frac 1{PQ}\sum_{i=1}^P\sum_{j=1}^Q f(X_i,Y_j).
$$
and define the functions
$$
f_1\colon x\mapsto \mathbb E\left[f(x,Y_1)\right]-\mu, \quad, f_2\colon y\mapsto \mathbb E\left[f(X_1,y)\right]-\mu,
$$
$$
f_3(x,y)=f(x,y)-f_1(x)-f_2(y)-\mu
$$
(this look very similar to Hoeffding's decomposition for U-statistics).
We thus get
$$
S_{P,Q}(f)-\mu=\frac 1P\sum_{i=1}^Pf_1(X_i)+\frac 1Q\sum_{j=1}^Q f_2(Y_j)+S_{P,Q}(f_3).
$$
We can show that for each positive $\varepsilon$,
$$
\sum_{M,N\geqslant 1}\mathbb P\left(\frac 1{2^{M+N}}\max_{1\leq P\leq 2^M}\max_{1\leq Q\leq 2^N} \lvert S_{P,Q}(f_3)\rvert >\varepsilon\right)<\infty.
$$
Indeed, we first use Chebyshev's inequality to reduce this to prove that
$$\tag{*}
\sum_{M,N\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left(\frac 1{2^{2(M+N)}}\max_{1\leq P\leq 2^M}\max_{1\leq Q\leq 2^N} \lvert S_{P,Q}(f_3)\rvert^2 \right)<\infty.
$$
To do so, observe that $\left(\max_{1\leq P\leq 2^M} \lvert S_{P,Q}(f_3)\rvert^2\right)_{Q\geqslant 1}=(M_Q)_{Q\geqslant 1}$ is a submartingale for the filtration
$\left(\mathcal F_Q\right)$, where $\mathcal F_Q=\sigma(X_i,1\leq i\leq 2^M,
Y_j,1\leqslant j\leqslant Q)$: by Jensen's inequality and monotonicity of conditional expectation,
$$
\mathbb E\left[M_Q\mid\mathcal F_{Q-1}\right]
\geqslant \max_{1\leq P\leq 2^M} \lvert \mathbb E\left[S_{P,Q}(f_3)\mid\mathcal F_{Q-1}\right]\rvert^2,
$$
and $\mathbb E\left[S_{P,Q}(f_3)\mid\mathcal F_{Q-1}\right]=S_{P,Q-1}(f_3)
+\sum_{i=1}^P \mathbb E\left[f_3(X_i,Y_{Q})\mid\mathcal F_{Q-1}\right]=S_{P,Q-1}(f_3)$, since $\mathbb E\left[Z\mid\mathcal F\vee\mathcal G\right]=\mathbb E\left[Z\mid\mathcal F\right]$ if $\mathcal G$ is independent of $\sigma(Z)\vee\mathcal F$,
$$
\mathbb E\left[f_3(X_i,Y_{Q})\mid\mathcal F_{Q-1}\right]=
\mathbb E\left[f_3(X_i,Y_{Q})\mid X_i\right]=0.
$$
Similarly, we can show that $\left(\lvert S_{P,2^N}(f_3)\rvert^2\right)_{P\geqslant 1}$ is a sub-martingale. By Doob's inequality, (*) reduces to
$$\tag{**}
\sum_{M,N\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left(\frac 1{2^{2(M+N)}}  \lvert S_{2^M,2^N}(f_3)\rvert^2 \right)<\infty.
$$
This follows from the fact that the summands are pairwise orthogonal.
In conclusion, the wanted convergence holds without imposing any rate on the convergence of $P$ and $Q$ to infinity. Some further remarks:

The convergence for $f_3$ holds actually if only one of the indexes $P$ and $Q$ goes to infinity.
Using Marcinkiewicz strong law of large numbers, we could show that for $1\leq p<2$,
$$
\min\{P^{1-1/p},Q^{1-1/p}\}\left(S_{P,Q}(f)-\mu\right)\to 0.
$$
The convergence $S_{P,Q}(f)-\mu$ can hold under less restrictive assumptions than a moment of order two.


Thank you -- this is impressively thorough. I am going through the steps slowly since I am not familiar with Martingale.

No problem. Let me know if you have questions.

How do you get to this level at martingale theory?! The answer is very impressive. @DavideGiraudo
